# Failed to update user profile with Microsoft Graph API via REST API

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to update user profile via Microsoft Graph API by a server side (Java) application without user consent.
I have an app in MS Azure which has the following "*Permissions to other applications*": "*Microsoft Graph - Read and write all user's full profiles*" as an "*Application Permission*", administrator had consent with these settings.

So I can fetch any user profile from our tenant. Also, with "*Read and write calendars in all mailboxes*" permission I can list and patch users' calendar entries. Using the same code snipets to update user profiles however does not works.

Here is a REST representation of the workflow,

obtain access token:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<my-tenant>/oauth2/token 
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

{
grant_type=client_credentials
&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com
&client_secret=<my-client-secret>
&client_id=<my-client-id>
}
```

so far so good, patch user profile:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/<my-tenant>/users/<target-user>
Authorization: Bearer <access_token from prev response>
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{"aboutMe": "happy"}
```

And the response is:

```
response code: 500
{
  "error": {
    "code": "-1, Microsoft.Office.Server.Directory.DirectoryObjectUnauthorizedAccessException",
    "message": "Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "<request-id>",
      "date": "2016-09-27T11:07:18"
    }
  }
}
```

According to the http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_update documentation I should have set "*User.ReadWrite; User.ReadWrite.All; Directory.ReadWrite.All*" scopes, unfortunately there is no such thing at manage.windowsazure.com app setting page but I believe "*Read and write all user's full profiles*" should do the trick.
The sample requests above have some data replaced with <> tags, they are oviously filled correctly during normal workflow. It is working perfectly for patching a calendar event (which is almost exactly the same except a minor changing in the url) but fails with patching the user object.

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft Graph has currently some limitations on operations at Users and Groups depending on the permission type. According to the site [Known issues](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/overview/release_notes), you can find out that there is a limitation: `Cannot perform any CRUD operations on User other than updating user HD photo and extended profile properties` for both `Delegated` and `Application` permission types.

Selecting `Directory.ReadWrite.All` permission (`Read and write directory data` in the [new Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com)), as indicated in `Alternative` column in the table in [Microsoft Graph permissions](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/overview/release_notes#microsoft-graph-permissions) section, should solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I also could reproduce this issue too.

Based on the test, the issue is relative to the specific filed(**aboutMe**) we were updating. And the patch user API works well for me when I update the **jobTitle** using the **Directory.ReadWrite.All**.

If you want the Microsoft Graph to support updating the **aboutMe** field, you can submit the feedback from [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).