# Update user's properties (aboutMe, skills) with app permission

Tags: json, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

When I am trying to update the user's `aboutMe` property via `/v1.0/users/[user-principal-name]` I get following error message:

```
{
    "error":
    {
        "code": "-1, Microsoft.Office.Server.Directory.DirectoryObjectUnauthorizedAccessException",
        "message": "Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.",
        "innerError":
        {
            "request-id": "a0112fff-de9a-4917-b627-c4103a04a105",
            "date": "2018-03-22T11:02:46"
        }
    }
}
```

What I have done far:

- Added application permissions `User.ReadWrite.All` and `Directory.ReadWrite.All` to registered app under `apps.dev.microsoft.com`
- Concent for app was granted by admin via `https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenant]/adminconsent?client_id=[client-id]&state=12345&redirect_uri=[redirect-uri]`

I am able to update the user's profile image or a property like `mobilePhone`.

What am I doing wrong/is it not possible to update those attributes?

Comment: Are you using Azure AD Connect to sync with an onprem AD?

Comment: I talked to one of our infrastructure guys and he said something about "AD Connect", yes. Is there a problem with that? Sorry, but I do not check all the coherences of the O365 world yet.

Comment: This isn't an O365 issue. It's due to Azure AD Connect being used to sync your onprem AD to Azure AD. Any fields that it copies are locked down and only editable at their source (local AD).

Comment: I talked to our infra guy again and he told me that these properties (aboutMe, skills) are not synced from any other system. They are not Azure AD properties but Sharepoint Online properties. Do you have any other thoughts/ideas?

Comment: Which OAuth grant are you using?

Comment: I am using 'client_credentials' for 'grant_type' to get token via https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenant]/oauth2/v2.0/token

Comment: You may want to try re-executing the Admin Consent flow just to be sure. You should be able to updates these properties using `User.ReadWrite.All`.

Comment: Re-executed the Admin Consent flow, but unfortunately did not help. I found following post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39725485/failed-to-update-user-profile-with-microsoft-graph-api-via-rest-api from 2016. Maybe it is still not possible to update these fields? As already mentioned, I updated e.g. profile image and mobilePhone attribute successfully.