# PATCH user request with birthday or hireDate returns 500 error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am unable to update the birthday and hireDate properties for users in my directory.

The following request returns a 500 Internal Server Error

> PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/[removed] HTTP/1.1
>   SdkVersion: Graph-dotnet-1.10.0
>   Authorization: Bearer [removed]
>   Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
>   Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>   Host: graph.microsoft.com
>
> {"hireDate":"1989-10-02T04:00:00Z"}

HTTP Response

> HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
>   Content-Type: application/json
>   ...
>
> Microsoft.Office.Server.Directory.DirectoryObjectUnauthorizedAccessException. Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.

[Azure AD App Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSJHQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I assume you want update user's birthday or hireDate through the Graph API.

From the returned response, your permission was denied to update the user's profile.

We should add the following permission: 'Directory.ReadWrite.All'.

To do that, we should add the Directory.ReadWrite.All scope in your code when we request an accesstoken.

Comment: So the screenshot in my last message shows that I have the Directory.ReadWrite.All assigned to my app and per the documentation at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service#4-get-an-access-token app tokens will receive all pre-configured permissions when using the .default scope which my application does

Comment: According to your description, I have find the solution at [this document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39725485/failed-to-update-user-profile-with-microsoft-graph-api-via-rest-api/39911494#39911494). It show that `Cannot perform any CRUD operations on User other than updating user HD photo and extended profile properties for both Delegated and Application permission types.`

Comment: I wonder if anyone from Microsoft can confirm because the link you provided is over 2 years old and I couldn't find that statement anywhere in the Microsoft Graph documentation. I did upvote your response though. Thanks

Comment: So, you can submit the feedback from [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/). If you have some solution, please post your answer